# How to turn this working A/B optimization program into more pythonic code?

Tags: python, optimization, python-3.x

I have a working solution for the given problem of A/B Optimization, but you as an experienced Python (3) developer will agree with me, that this solution is not very pythonic at all.

My Question here is: *How do I make this code more pythonic?*

It's a very procedural process that one would expect from a Basic program, but not from a Python program. Please help me to become a better coder and make pythonic code by working through this example with me.

Here's the problem and my solution.

### Problem

> In this test you will be given a CSV containing the results of a website's A/B homepage test. The site is simultaneously testing 5 design variables (A, B, C, D, and E) and tracking if users clicked on the signup button (Z). Each line of the CSV represents a visitor to the homepage, what they saw, and if they clicked or not. The A-E variables will have values of 1-5, representing which version of that design element was shown to the user. The Z variable will contain either a 1 to represent that the user clicked signup, or a 0 to represent that the user did not.
>
> ```
> A B C D E Z
> 1 3 1 2 4 1
> 3 2 1 5 5 0
> 4 3 2 2 5 1
> 5 5 2 3 4 0
> 2 4 1 3 4 0
> ...
> ```
>
> Your task will be to determine the single combination of A-E values that will make users most likely to click the signup button. Assume the effects of each A-E value are mutually exclusive. If two values of a variable are equally optimal, choose the lesser value. You will enter the answer in the form of a 5-digit number, the first digit being the optimal A value, the second being the optimal B value, the third being the optimal C value, etc.

### Solution

```
from urllib.request import urlopen

def getBestDesign(url):
    data = urlopen(url).readlines()
    A = {}; B = {}; C = {}; D = {}; E = {};
    A['1'] = 0
    A['2'] = 0
    A['3'] = 0
    A['4'] = 0
    A['5'] = 0
    B['1'] = 0
    B['2'] = 0
    B['3'] = 0
    B['4'] = 0
    B['5'] = 0
    C['1'] = 0
    C['2'] = 0
    C['3'] = 0
    C['4'] = 0
    C['5'] = 0
    D['1'] = 0
    D['2'] = 0
    D['3'] = 0
    D['4'] = 0
    D['5'] = 0
    E['1'] = 0
    E['2'] = 0
    E['3'] = 0
    E['4'] = 0
    E['5'] = 0
    for row in data:
        row = row.decode(encoding='UTF-8').split('\t')
        if row[5].startswith('1'):
            A[str(row[0])] += 1
            B[str(row[1])] += 1
            C[str(row[2])] += 1
            D[str(row[3])] += 1
            E[str(row[4])] += 1
    maxclicks_A = max(A.values())
    maxclicks_B = max(B.values())
    maxclicks_C = max(C.values())
    maxclicks_D = max(D.values())
    maxclicks_E = max(E.values())
    for k, v in A.items():
        if v == maxclicks_A:
            print('A: ', k)
    for k, v in B.items():
        if v == maxclicks_B:
            print('B: ', k)
    for k, v in C.items():
        if v == maxclicks_C:
            print('C: ', k)
    for k, v in D.items():
        if v == maxclicks_D:
            print('D: ', k)
    for k, v in E.items():
        if v == maxclicks_E:
            print('E: ', k)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    url = input('Url: ')
    getBestDesign(url)
```

Answer (score 3):

There is *massive* code duplication in your script. Basically you are doing the same things for `A` through `E`, so you could just put them in a list of dictionaries and use loops. Also, by using `defaultdict` you do not have to initialize them per hand (and even if not you could use a loop for this, too). Also, I'd recommend removing the code for transforming the URL to a 2D array from the function, and using just `split()` without `'\t'` the code works as well, and is somewhat more robust to other input formats.

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
from collections import defaultdict

def getBestDesign(data):
    # this list holds all your A, B, C, ... dicts, with defaultvalues
    ABCDE = [defaultdict(int) for i in range(5)]
    for row in data:
        if row[5] == '1':
            for i in range(5):
                ABCDE[i][row[i]] += 1
    for i in range(5):
        maxclicks = max(ABCDE[i].values())
        for k, v in ABCDE[i].items():
            if v == maxclicks:
                print('ABCDE'[i], ": ", k) # note the ''!
                # break # optional, stop after first "max" value

if __name__ == "__main__":
    url = input('Url: ')
    lines = urlopen(url).readlines()
    data = [line.decode(encoding='UTF-8').split() for line in lines]
    getBestDesign(data)
```

The algorithms is still basically the same as yours, and I think that it can still be improved. Probably you could use `numpy` to treat the input data as a matrix and do all sorts of useful matrix operations on the data. Further, you could probably use `collections.Counter` or `itertools.groupby` for counting the good combinations, reducing the whole thing to two or three lines.

---

Here's another version, even shorter, doing some preprocessing and using `collections.Counter`:

```
def getBestDesign(data):
    filtered = [d[:-1] for d in data if d[5] == '1']
    for i, d in enumerate(zip(*filtered)):
        key, maxclicks = Counter(d).most_common(1)[0]
        print("{0}: {1} ({2})".format("ABCDE"[i], key, maxclicks))
```

Let's explain this line by line:

- the `filtered` [list comprehension](http://docs.python.org/3.3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) holds just the lines from `data` where the user has clicked; as this is already filtered, we can drop the last column with `[:-1]`
- in the loop, we iterate the data columns -- [`zip(*...)`](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#zip) basically [transposes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4937526/1639625) the matrix -- using `enumerate`, which yields the index `i` and the actual data `d` at that index
- the [`Counter`](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) class is used to count each variant and to return the `most_common` one
- finally, we `print` the result using [`string.format`](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/stdtypes.html#str.format), using the index `i` to get the respective letter from the string `"ABCDE"`

Comment: +1, but it seems wrong to me that you have one loop over `ABCDE[i].values()` to find `maxclicks` and then a second loop over `ABCDE[i].items()` to find the key. Better to do this in a single loop: `k, maxclicks = max(ABCDE[i].items(), key=operator.itemgetter(1))`

Comment: @GarethRees You are right! When I wrote this, I thought "this seems wrong, there has to be a better way" all the time, but did not catch it. Thanks! (Then again, this way there will always be only _one_ max value, whereas there may be multiple.)